# php DateTime acting weird

Tags: php, datetime, date-math

So i have this code to determine difference between present time and datetime field value from database.

This code gives weird output (samples below) for dates that are not in same year.

```
$deadline      = new DateTime($someDeadline, new DateTimeZone('CET'));
$time_now      = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone('CET'));
$overdue_until = $time_now->diff($deadline);
echo $overdue_until->format('%R %d day/s, %h hours, %i minutes');
```

Example results:

Monday 9th of February 2015 05:28:23 PM  gets the difference + 28 day/s, 17 hours, 6 minutes from current time.

Wednesday 14th of January 2015 11:28:43 AM  + 2 day/s, 10 hours, 34 minutes

Comment: Timezone CET exists for backward compatibility reasons and shouldn't be used. See the [PHP page](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` gets you up to 31 days. After that it resets to zero and months are incremented. If you want the total number if days you need to use `%a`

```
echo $overdue_until->format('%R %a day/s, %h hours, %i minutes');
```

[Demo 1](https://eval.in/233724)
[Demo 2](https://eval.in/233725)